# Adding self-signed SSL certificate for libcurl

Tags: c, ssl, libcurl, self-signed

I am using libcurl in my C application to communicate with an HTTPS server that I have set up. I generated a self-signed certificate on that server that I wish to use with curl.

I am aware of setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to 0 to bypass the SSL verification, but I wish to add the generated certificate to curl's "valid" CA certificates.

I have tried setting CURLOPT_CAPATH and CURLOPT_SSLCERT to the location of the server SSL public key, but it fails to pass the verification.

How can I add my own CA/Self-signed certificate so that libcurl will successfully validate it?

Comment: Add the update as an answer. btw, `--libcurl` curl option can generate libcurl-using source code (to see what options you could use) if you already have a working curl-command.

Answer (score 4):

To add a self-signed certificate, use **CURLOPT_CAINFO**

To retrieve the SSL public certificate of a site, use

```
openssl s_client -connect www.site.com:443 | tee logfile
```

The certificate is the portion marked by `----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----` and
`---END CERTIFICATE----`.

Save that certificate into a file, and use curl in a manner like so:

```
CURL* c = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(c, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.site.com");
curl_easy_setopt(c, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/path/to/the/certificate.crt");
curl_easy_setopt(c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_easy_perform(c);
curl_easy_cleanup(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you kind of mix "Certificate Authority" files and "Certificate" files which confuses me.

> How can I add my own CA/Self-signed certificate so that libcurl will
>   successfully validate it?

This might be seen as a complementary answer to the one above.
In the case you want to add a self-signed CA (every root-CA is self-signed) so that libcurl will successfully validate a website's certificate, which has been generated by the CA, then continue reading.

With CURLOPT_CAINFO you need to pass the "Certificate Authority" file (CA) that was used when generating the (non-CA) certificate of the site you want to verify.

(I do not know if this option works by passing it a non-CA certificate, the documentation is not really clear on this, and the previous answer has 2 up-votes, so if anyone has tested it please comment)

You can also pass a Certificate Authority chain file that contains the CA that was used, in case it was not a root-CA.

Here's a little tutorial I've found that can help you test your solution:

Creating a private root CA:
[http://www.flatmtn.com/article/setting-openssl-create-certificates](http://www.flatmtn.com/article/setting-ssl-certificates-apache)

Creating a site certificate:
http://www.flatmtn.com/article/setting-ssl-certificates-apache